# Authorization to upload files to Dropbox on company's business account

Tags: c#, dropbox-api, .net-4.8

I have a C# (.Net Framework 4.8) desktop application that we were, at one time, using the static Dropbox token to send up files to our account. We use this application to zip and upload a file to account on a couple of servers.

Recently, we've been getting the message:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
> Dropbox.Api.AuthException: expired_access_token

I've read that the tokens are only active for 4 hours now and that you need to reacquire a new token. We have the Dropbox application status set to `Development` and we are not releasing this application to the public, it's used internally only.

My first question is, do we have the option to get a long term access token without having to request a new one every time we upload a file?

If we can get a long term token, how do I go about getting one? When I goto the Dropbox website and get a new token, it starts with `sl_`, which from what I've read means short lived. This makes sense since the token does eventually expire.

If we are required to reacquire a new token, can I do it without requiring the application being prompted to authenticate the session through a web browser?

What am I doing wrong?

```
private async Task<int> UploadFile()
{    
  var newargs = _appParms.Reverse().Take(_appParms.Length - 2).Reverse().ToList();
  foreach (var newarg in newargs)
  {
    if (!File.Exists(_appParms[2]))
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"File does not exist: {newarg}");
      continue;
    }

    var filename = Path.GetFileName(newarg);
    var client = CreateDropBoxInstance();

    var path = $"/{_appParms[1]}";
    await CreateFolder(client, path);

    var list = await ListFolder(client, path);
    var firstFile = list.Entries.FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsFile && i.Name == filename);
    if (firstFile != null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("File already exists on server, failed to upload.");
      Console.WriteLine("Change the upload folder or file name and try again.");
      return (int)Enums.ReturnCode.FailFileAlreadyExists;
    }

    await ChunkUpload2(client, path, newarg);
  }
  return (int)Enums.ReturnCode.Success;
}

private static DropboxClient CreateDropBoxInstance()
{
  // Specify socket level timeout which decides maximum waiting time when no bytes are
  // received by the socket.
  var httpClient = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler { ReadWriteTimeout = 10 * 1000 })
  {
    // Specify request level timeout which decides maximum time that can be spent on
    // download/upload files.
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
  };

  try
  {
    var config = new DropboxClientConfig("DropBoxBackup")
    {
      HttpClient = httpClient
    };

    return new DropboxClient(AccessToken, config);

  }
  catch (HttpException e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception reported from RPC layer");
    Console.WriteLine("    Status code: {0}", e.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine("    Message    : {0}", e.Message);
    if (e.RequestUri != null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("    Request uri: {0}", e.RequestUri);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I'm confused as to how this works now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See : https://www.codemzy.com/blog/dropbox-long-lived-access-refresh-token#:~:text=When%20you%20generate%20an%20access,lived%20and%20doesn't%20expire.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is no longer offering the option for creating new long-lived access tokens. Dropbox is now issuing short-lived access tokens (and optional refresh tokens) instead of long-lived access tokens. You can find [more information on this migration here](https://dropbox.tech/developers/migrating-app-permissions-and-access-tokens#updating-access-token-type).

Apps can still get long-term access by requesting "offline" access though, in which case the app receives a "refresh token" that can be used to retrieve new short-lived access tokens as needed, without further manual user intervention. You can find more information in [the OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization). There's a basic outline of processing this flow in [this blog post](https://dropbox.tech/developers/using-oauth-2-0-with-offline-access) which may serve as a useful example.

When you use the official Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK, you do not need to implement all of the code for the OAuth flow yourself. The SDK will do most of the work for you. You can find [examples of using this here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/main/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples).